# Need SQL query to list user's current and possible purchases

Tags: sql, sql-server

Admittedly, I'm not great at joins :/

I have 3 tables and I want to connect them like this

Users.UserID -> Gateway.UserID, Gateway.ProgramID -> Programs.ProgramID

Gateway is a list of all programs a user has already subscribed to. When I output a table, programs where the user hasn't subscribed will have a subscribe link, rows where they have subscribed will contain a link to the program.

So the output, which I can handle (because of course that's the easy part) might look like something like:

```
Alpha   [Enter]
Beta    [Enter]
Charlie [Subscribe] - This will insert the row into Gateway
Delta   [Enter]
Foxtrot [Subscribe]
```

I appreciate any help that anyone provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @userId int;
set @userId = <your user ID>;

SELECT 
    p.ProgramId,
    (CASE WHEN g.ProgramID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IsSubscribed

FROM Programs p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Gateway g ON (g.ProgramID = p.ProgramID AND g.UserID = @userId)
```

Comment: Trying this right now, thanks for adding the IsSubscribed bit, I felt like that was too much to ask for since I could do it without.

Comment: There was a slight syntax error, I had to change it to CASE WHEN...IS NULL, rather than CASE...IF NULL.  It appears to be working great now, that's for the fast help.

Comment: I took liberty to change the title of your question to make it more specific

Comment: K, btw, "that's for the fast help" was a terrible typo lol. "Thanks for the fast help"